# Is there a way to know whether something was rounded up or down in python?

Tags: python, rounding

I basically want to know whether the result of my equation (which is a simple one like this `x / y`) was rounded up or down.
The reason is that I have two simple statements after the rounding line like this:

```
if h % 2 != 0: h = h + 1
if h % 4 != 0: h = h + 2
```

and based on the direction of the rounding I would choose the `+` or `-` operator, so if the result was rounded up and `h % 2 != 0` then it would be `h = h + 1` and if it was rounded down then `h = h - 1`.

Does `round()` give that kind of information?

Also, is my math correct? (I want the result to be dividable by 4)

Comment: Do you control the rounding part or have access to the unrounded result?

Comment: So `h = round(x/y)`? (And no, the result is a plain `int` or `float` value with no memory of where it came from.)

Comment: `round()` does not report that information.  But you can compare the unrounded result to the rounded result to see which is bigger, which will tell you.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Yes and yes.

Comment: @JohnGordon I thought about another way initially, but didn't know how to implement it. It was something like this: Postpone the rounding and based on the resulting float decide which operator to use (i.e. if less than 5 then `-` else `+`) and then round it.

Comment: Are you trying to round to the nearest multiple of 2 and 4?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, nearest multiple of 4 (which would be a multiple of 2 as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to round to 4 directly :

```
import math

h = 53.75
rounded = math.round(h / 4) * 4

if (rounded > h):
  print("Rounded up by " + str(rounded - h))
else:
   print("Rounded down by " + str(h - rounded))
```

Comment: `math.floor()` always rounds down.

Comment: Yes, yes it was a mistake, it's just edited. Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain your math a bit? Will it always give me the nearest multiple of four?

Comment: Let's say that you want to round 23 to a multiple of 5 : `23 / 5.0 => 4.6`, then `math.round(4.6) => 5` and finally `5 * 5 => 25`

Comment: @dspr I got that part, just wanted to know the theory behind it. Anyway I changed my code based on your code above and now I only got 1 statement instead of 2:
`if h % 4 != 0: h = D(h / 4).quantize(D('1'), rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP) * 4`
Thanks for the tip.

Comment: **A**. h/4 give you the position of h in terms of "blocks of 4" stating from 0.   
**B**. You're averaging to the nearest block beginning using round. This will always correspond to the nearest multiple of 4, although it's not in the right scale yet.   
**C**. You're going back to the original number scale by multiplying by the value of each block.

Answer (score 1):

Using round() if the number after the given decimal is:

- >=5 that + 1 will be added to the final value.
- <5 that the final value will return as is to the mentioned decimals.

But you can use `ceil` or `floor` from the math package where it always rounds up or down, respectively.

```py
import math

>>> math.ceil(5.2)
6
>>> math.floor(5.9)
5
```

Comment: That way I'd have to always check the result manually which would be counter-intuitive in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to know whether `3.9` and `4.4` were rounded. You can do something like this:

```py
def is_rounded_down(val, ndigits=None):
    return round(val, ndigits) < val
```

Then you can simply call the function to find out

```
>>> is_rounded_down(3.9)
False
>>> is_rounded_down(4.4)
True
```

By default `round()` doesn't give that information, so you need to check yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For Python 2.X integer division returns an integer and always rounds down.

```
add@LM1756:~$ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Sep 26 2018, 18:42:22)
>>> print 8/3
2
>>> print type(5/2)
<type 'int'>
```

For Python 3.X integer division returns a float, and so there is no rounding.

```
add@LM1756:~$ python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39)
>>> print(8/3)
2.6666666666666665
>>> type(8/3)
<class 'float'>
>>>
```